# Reusable auto-scrolling canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, scroll

Okay I made a Scolling canvas (sometimes I put buttons in it that open my programs or do other stuff) it is working perfectly. But I tried making it into a .dll but I noticed that the method I am using is worthless for a .dll as it autoscrolls upon drop and I can't add more to it. so what I want is a empty canvas (or anything really) that auto-scrolls the content and will let me add more items into it. example: buttons, text block, labels etc. and it will scroll all of them.

Edit: I want to be able to drag the control from the toolbox into the window and then add buttons etc onto it and it will auto-scroll them.

Example below. xaml only.. thinking to make it the way I want it has to be coded in c# not xaml. since once it is added as a user control you cannot add other controls, toolbox items to it and expect them to auto-scroll..

```
<Canvas ClipToBounds="True" x:Name="scrollerCanvas" Height="588">
    <Grid x:Name="OurContainer" Height="588" Background="{x:Null}" ClipToBounds="False">
        <Grid.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1087,588" RadiusX="30" RadiusY="30" />
        </Grid.Clip>
        <StackPanel Height="800" Margin="1">
            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="scroll" />
            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>

        </StackPanel>

        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                From="620" To="-450"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="scroll" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
                                Duration="0:0:28" SpeedRatio=".8" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a ScrollViewer with a Canvas inside it.

Comment: already know that lol I want it re-usable and it will be a toolbox item. I want it to be animated and auto scroll. I already have an auto-scrolling canvas but I have to remake it every time lol I want to make it once and then drag n drop to a form and then put buttons etc. in it and it will scroll them

Comment: what i understand is, you need a designer just as in visual studio for form design. the only difference is that you need it to be scrollable.for that you can drag the scrollviewer from toolbox and then can add more items to it.

Comment: ya that can be implemented using user control.

Comment: mind telling me how instead of saying it can be implemented. so far I make the user control but once it is added to a window it autoscrolls but doesn't scroll any items I put on it >.>

Comment: Sorry for not replying for a while. here is sample code of just what you need to do the auto-scrolling but I need to make it so you can add toolbox items after adding the control to mainwindow or other windows.